# Why doesnt this run continuously when i push the continuous button?

Tags: java, android

```
public class TestingActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);

ScheduledFuture now = null;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //oncreate
}
public void rollthedice()
{
//rollthedice
}


 public void onClick(View view)
{

    Runnable runner = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            rollthedice();
        }
    };


    if(view.equals(continuous))
    {
    if(now == null)
        now = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runner, 0, 250, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    else
        return;
    }
    if(view.equals(stop))
    {
        if(now != null)
        {
            now.cancel(true);
            now = null;
        }

        else
            return;
    }
    if(view.equals(roll))
        rollthedice();
    if(view.equals(exit))
        System.exit(0);
}
```

I used it in a Java application and it worked fine, i put it into android project and it doesnt work i want the continuous button to run rollthedice() continuously and the stop button to stop it then continuous to start it again and stop back and forth

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? I dont think you should use equals() here, simple == should suffice

Comment: I'm fairly sure that you will find the problem if you add some logs to your code and/or step through it with the debugger.

Comment: ok i changed ==, so what happens is i hit roll and it performes rollthedice() once fine, if i hit the continuous button it seems to not do anything but if i hit the roll button it skips one count of roll being pushed, for rollthedice() #of times being executed, so continuous only does rollthedice() once and #of times being executed doesnt update on the gui even the one time it does go? i want continuous to run rollthedice() 4 times a second until the stop button is pressed, the one time continuous runs rollthedice() cant be done again unless stopped and hit continuous again

Comment: so the scheduleAtFixedRate IS executed but the runnable IS NOT scheduled for execution? Are you sure your rollthedice is not throwing an exception?

Comment: when i hit the roll button, rollthedice() runs fine, everything that is supposed to happen happens, gui updated and everything, its just continuous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the onCLick is executed?
Did you call

```
continuous.setOnClickListener(this);
stop.setOnClickListener(this);
```

etc?

Comment: can you try to print the classname of view inside the onClick?Also, try using == in place of equal(). should be the same,but you never know

Comment: Log.I("MyApp",view.getClass().getName()) - just to check "view" is a Button. It will also confirm the onClick gets called.

Comment: Log.I("MyApp",view.getClass().getName()) just after the schedule line - just to check "view" is a Button. It will also confirm the onClick gets called and the schedule is started.

Comment: on the logcat it came up myapp android.widget.button, i guess that means it was pressed, it doesnt work though

Comment: Well at least we restricted the problem if the line is logged right after the scheduleAtFixedRate we know it gets inside that if and that's the line not working ffor some reason. next - put a logline inside the roll dice to see if it is executed but maybe just not painted

Comment: i put the log at the end of rollthedice() and when i hit continuous it didnt come up on the logcat, then i hit roll and it came back on the logcat, but on the gui where it says times rolled it says 2 and i hit continuous once and roll once

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to add it some while loop with a flag, try this:

```
public void run()
{
while (runningFlag){
//do something here
}
}
```

At the start you need to set the flag to true and then start the thread, and when you want it to stop set the flag to false.

Comment: i should change the runnable?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a while loop and set the condition to true to stop it (because of the !). You should also highly consider having the rolling in a separate thread. If you do you may or may not need a handler.

```
boolean mPaused = false;

while(!mPaused) {
    doSomething();
}

//to stop it set mPaused = true
//to resume call the method again
```

Handler

```
//called by
Message msg0 = new Message();
msg0.obj = "someting";
handler.sendMessage(msg0);

private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.obj.equals("something")) {
            doSomething();
        }
    }
};
```